# Getting Resources$NotFoundException with RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm getting the following error:

```
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x0
```

I am just creating a number list using `RecyclerView`:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class SongRVAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SongViewHolder> {
    private Context context;

    public SongRVAdapter(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }


    @Override
    public SongViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.song_info_row, parent, false);

        return new SongViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(SongViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Log.d("CodeKamp", "onBindViewHolder called for position " + position);
        holder.titleTextView.setText(position);
        holder.durationTextView.setText("00:" + position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return 10;
    }
}
```

Comment: asked bazillion times `TextView.setText` with int as parameter need existing string resource id ... you are passing 0 which is not valid string resource id ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't pass `int` values to `setText()`, else it will try and look up a String resource matching that `int` ID. So

```
holder.titleTextView.setText(position);
```

needs to be changed to

```
holder.titleTextView.setText(String.valueOf(position));
```

to convert `position` into a String.